# How does `containsInAnyOrder` compare items?

Tags: java, testing, contains, assert, hamcrest

I've got a `CustomField` class and I've overriden the equals and hashcode methods. But when I try to compare 2 lists of `CustomField` objects, it fails.
Why wouldn't the `containsInAnyOrder` work in the following:

```
Overrides:
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CustomField that = (CustomField) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, that.id) &&
                Objects.equals(this.name, that.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.id, this.name);
    }
```

```
        List<CustomField> actual = ImmutableList.of(
                new CustomField(1L, "1L"),
                new CustomField(2L, "2L"),
                new CustomField(3L, "3L")
        );
        List<CustomField> expected = ImmutableList.of(
                new CustomField(1L, "1L"),
                new CustomField(2L, "2L"),
                new CustomField(3L, "3L")
        );
        assertThat(actual, containsInAnyOrder(expected)); /// why does this fail?
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: It's in the question description. The `assertThat` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder(T...)

`containsInAnyOrder` expects an array of elements to match with the provided `actual` list.
You are passing `expected` as list.  And `actual` is not a List of List.
So, it will try to search for an entire list as an element in `actual`.

Probably you will need to use `containsInAnyOrder(expected.toArray())`.

I.e.

```
assertThat(actual, containsInAnyOrder(expected.toArray()));
```

Try it out.

Comment: There's really no good reason to first create the expected list, then call `toArray` on it. Just inline it with `containsAnyOrder(field1, field2, field3)`.

Comment: Yes, that is also correct. No need to create an `expected` list. I just followed it with minimal changes.  But yes, pass all the values as var-args.